# How to authorize a user in linux c language environment?

Tags: c, linux, ftp, authorization

I'm developing a ftp program. The users of the ftp client are the ones exist in the servers user group. On the client side it inputs the username and the password, and the server side tell if in the current system there is a user named the username and the password match the one the client side sends to it. I'm having trouble getting a certain user's password because of the shadow system(I used the pw = getpwnam( "username" ) then pw->pw_password, and it only return an x).

Now I know it's a bit hard to get the password of a user directly, so I'm wondering if there is a kind of an authorization system to complete to task. Something like I provide it with the username and the password and it tells me if the password is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my head is to run `su <user>` and then pass the password to it, then you would just need to check what `su` responds.

Comment: How can it be used in c language? Is there any examples?